# problem with the css overflow: hidden property

Tags: jquery, html, css, dhtml

I'm having a problem with displaying a popup that's rendered within the html and then just toggled to show and hide it.  My problem is that this popup sits in a div that has an overflow: hidden property and it means that some of the popup background graphics cross over the width of the overflow: hidden div.  this causes a display issue as the width of the popup is cut off where it crosses the overflow setting.

Is it possible to get around this?

many thanks!!!!!
James

Comment: If you could offer a link to your page (or a jsbin demo) it might help us help you. Off the top of my head, does the pop-up have `position: absolute;`? If not, it might be worth trying (since that will take it out of the document's flow, and *perhaps* allow it to overflow the div's boundaries.

Comment: Do you really need the overflow:hidden attribute on the container div? Have you considered setting the overflow:hidden attribute on individual child elements instead? (Or use a separate container for the stuff that might overflow)

Answer (score 1):

If the popup is to appear on top of your website stick it after the main markup just before the  tag. Then use the language making it appear to position it where you need when it pops up.

It should be fairly straight forward if you're using jQuery.

E.g.

```
<div id="main-website-with-overflow-hidden>
      <!-- Web page stuff -->
</div>

<div id="popop">
      <!-- Popup stuff -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with scroll bars you could try this css on your container div

```
.containerDiv {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

If you would only want vertical/horizontal you could try

```
 .containerDiv {
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply although i cant use scroll bars, unfortunately.

Comment: Crappy... so you do want it to overflow?  What about using javascript to set the overflow property to show?

Comment: demo is available here...  if you use firebug or other try removing the OutboundDaySliderContainer overflow property and you'll see the orange bubble display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Give the pop up div a higher z-index than the div it is contained in

```
div#container{z-index:1;}
div#popup{z-index: 10;}
```